Can I use two SCRs instead of the relay in an EVSE charging station?
I'm designing an 11.1 kW AC EVSE, and the conventional architecture is to use a relay to allow current flow to the electric vehicle's onboard charger. However, I was considering replacing the relay with an anti-parallel configuration of SCRs. Is it possible to do this? Could using thyristors instead of the relay affect the operation of the electric vehicle's onboard charger in any way?

Circuit with conventional relay in an AC EVSE

Proposed circuit to replace the relay


SCRs will have leakage. This may be a safety consideration. Relays don’t have the same issue.

SCRs can't be easily deactivated whilst current flows and it's not clear from your question how this will occur or, if it's needed. You need to post a schematic.

Relays have a huge power dissipation advantage over thyristors.  Hard to beat mΩ contact resistance.

Also, if one of the devices is fried, pulsating DC can be sent to the charger input, possibly further cooking components such as transformers.
